# GCD of $(x^3+2x+1,2x^2+3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

I'm meant to find the greatest common divisor of polynomials $x^3+2x+1$ and $2x^2+3$ and their respective Bezout coefficients in fields $Q[x]$ and $Z5[x]$.

Quite lost I start the algorithm for $Q[x]$ getting from $x^3+2x+1=(2x^2+3)(1/2x) + (1/2x+1) \rightarrow (2x^2+3)=(1/2x+1)(4x-8) + (11)$ which is where I stopped.

I'm sure this is rather basic but how do I deal with the situation now as I have only been given numerical exercises.

As for the Z5 I'm even more confused since I expected an easier solution but have gotten $x^3+2x+1=(2x^2+3)(3x)+(3x+1) \rightarrow (2x^2+3)=(3x+1)(4x+2) + 1.$

Which would lead me to conclusion that GCD of both is 1 but am unable to confirm/prove it.

Thanks for your time

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Bézout%27s_Lemma

Comment: For Q, you basically said that the gcd in question is the same as $\gcd({1\over2}x+1,11)$. Why did you stop at that?

Comment: It leads you to the conclusion that the GCD of both is $1$, and you DID confirm/prove it, by your calculations! I think you did a great job. Your calculations seem to be perfectly correct, and they prove that the GCD is $1$ in both cases (with $\mathbb{Q}$ and with $\mathbb{Z}_5$. .. If you would like to do something more to increase your confidence, try using the "extended Euclidean algorithm" (back-substitution) to solve $1 = (x^3+2x+1) \cdot A(x) + (2x^2+3) \cdot B(x)$ in both cases. But really, I think what you have done already is fine.